# Bottom navigation view icons colors does not appear correctly

Tags: android

I am having a problem with this BottomNavigationView library    https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx

The colours I stated in this xml file don't appear correctly

> color_state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_checked="true" android:alpha="1"/>
        <item android:color="#bdbdbd" android:state_checked="false" />
    </selector>
```

As you can see, I have set the `state_checked = true` color to black but instead it appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyIMz.png).

The same happens to `state_checked = false`,
Any body know how can I solve this

Here is the BottomNavigation code:

```
<com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/color_state"
        android:id="@+id/bottomnav"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/state"
        android:background="@android:color/white"

        >



    </com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx>
```

Comment: Did you get it to work in the end? I am facing the same problem, with the same library, for APIs ABOVE KitKat, for the icons in the menu that are not in state_checked (state_checked works fine).

Comment: Your example helped me. Just put my custom_color.xml into /res/animator and then its works

Answer (score 2):

itemIconTint should be color resource not drawable, app:itemIconTint="@drawable/color_state" should change to  app:itemIconTint="@color/color_state"

Comment: I created a directory in the res folder called color and put my xml in there but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a really dumb thing - after hours of debugging, learning about differences between supplying @color and @drawable and differences between various states of the Views, it turned out that I had both `layout` and `layout-v21` folders in my `res` directory and I was only editing the former.